# Is there a way to revert neo4j graph db to a former state, perhaps using logical logs?

Tags: neo4j

Is there a procedure or are there instructions or is it possible to revert a neo4j graphdb database to a previous state after changes have been made and committed?  So, for example, if someone made changes to the DB and then committed them, is there a way to back those changes out or to restore the db to the state it was in before those changes were made?  I am using Community edition v. 2.0.0-M06 on a linux platform.  Logical logs are being kept. (keep_logical_logs=true).  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Is your question theoretical or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: It's theoretical in the sense that I don't have a need to roll back an existing db.  I have been tasked with determining if it is possible to do this, and if so to document how it is done.  I am still a neo4j newbie.

Comment: Glad it is not a rollback emergency, hindsight beforehand is very nice. For a planned scenario your first point of call might be [the backup docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/operations-backup.html), (applicable if you use the 'Enterprise Edition'). Since you ask specifically about the logical logs I won't put an answer since a restore from log is beyond my ken. Hth.

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, at the moment we are still in the Community edition phase, but not forever.  I appreciate your taking the time to read and respond to my question.   If anyone else might know if the logical logs can be leveraged in this way, please do share your knowledge on the subject.

Comment: for reference, this has been answered at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/9KQeTyWNePI/ZqD1PjthU_YJ